# Pattern for matching pieces of url

Tags: regex, routes

I have the following pattern: www.domain.com:8051/(.***)/(.*)

And the following two urls:

www.domain.com:8051/first/second

www.domain.com:8051/first/second/third/fourth

Both urls matches. But I only want to match the first one. What must I do to exclude the "/" as a character to match?

Thanks,
Joan.

Answer (score 1):

In order to exclude character you should use `[^<characters to exclude>]` so in your case:

```
www.domain.com:8051/([^/]*)/([^/]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a greedy regex quantifier when you need to use the reluctant quantifier.

Rather than `.*`, use `.*?`.  I found [this cheat sheet](http://www.omicentral.com/cheatsheets/JavaRegularExpressionsCheatSheet.pdf) extremely helpful when first learning how to use regular expression.

`www.domain.com:8051/(.*?)/(.*?)`

EDIT:
After messing around with the pattern for a bit, I haven't been able to come up with a pattern which works, but you could check that the above pattern is found, and the following pattern is not: `www.domain.com:8051/(.*?)/(.*?)/$`

Comment: Wouldn't this match the second URL?

Comment: That wouldn't match either of them because there's no trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

If those are the only patterns, why not just split on "/" and check the length?

You still have access to the components.